# Swift currentLocation return nil

Tags: ios, swift, authorization, cllocationmanager

I need to get the current location of the user, but currentLocation return alawas nil. However, CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus is authorizedWhenInUse and on the Map, the pin of my location si correct.

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class Location: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var currentLocation: CLLocation? = nil
    var showUserLocation: Bool?
    var isAuthorised = false {
        didSet {
            if isAuthorised {
                locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
                showUserLocation = true
            } else {
                locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
                currentLocation = nil
                showUserLocation = false
            }
        }
    }

    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override init() {
        super.init()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        currentLocation = locations.last
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        isAuthorised = (status == .authorizedWhenInUse)
    }

    func distance(of position: Position) -> CLLocationDistance {
        let location = CLLocation(latitude: position.lat, longitude: position.lng)
        return currentLocation?.distance(from: location) ?? Double.infinity
    }
}

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    var position:Position {
        return Position(lat: latitude, lng: longitude)
    }
}
```

Thank you !

**EDIT : I HAVE FIND THE SOLUTION !!!**

In my MapViewController, I loaded the annotation before init the Map. So, the function distance was execute BEFORE the function didUpdateLocations.

I am very apologize for the lost time...
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Does control enter `didSet` block of `isAuthorised` variable? `didUpdateLocations` function body? Why don't you also compare authorization status with `.authorizedAlways`?

Comment: are you getting values of locations.last in didUpdatesLocations ?

Answer (score -1):

I have written the full code to fetch the current location through the `LocationManager` class. This code is within the `LocationManager.swift` file.

#### LocationManager.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

typealias LocationHandler = (_ location: CLLocation?, _ error: Error?) -> Void

class LocationManager: NSObject {

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    var locationHandler: LocationHandler?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        setupLocation()
    }

    fileprivate func setupLocation() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
        locationManager?.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    public func findCurrentLocation(_ handler: LocationHandler?) {
        if isLocationPermissionEnabled() {
            locationHandler = handler
            locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    public func isLocationPermissionEnabled() -> Bool {
        let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        return (status == .denied || status == .notDetermined) ? false : true
    }

    func locationManager(_: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let currentLocation = locations.last {
            self.locationHandler?(currentLocation, nil)
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        self.locationHandler?(nil, error)
    }
}
```